# COM over USB with .NET to interface with 3rd party hardware

Tags: .net, com, hardware, usb

I have a project where I have to interact with two different devices that supply data via COM over USB. The client is telling me that this can be done easily with HyperTerminal but I am unfamiliar with it. I am coding with .NET 2.0 (but can use 3.5 if necessary).

What would be the easiest/quickest way to obtain the data from these hardware devices? Is there a control? Library? Something else, that is standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx). You can then use Read(), ReadLine(), etc. to read data from the 3rd party hardware.